# Адрес сайта с страницы

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно с помощью javascript  получить адрес сайта с страницы текста. Например у меня есть страница с текстом html в ней есть указанная ссылка на сайт но просто как текст, вопрос как получить адрес сайта.
Буду раз советам и кускам кодов или алгоритмам, заранее спасибо.

Comment: Спарсить? Сайт ваш? Ссылка 1? Всегда в 1  и том же месте? Сайт ссылки статичен? Какой вид имеет ссылка?

Comment: смотрите регулярки, и например [match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

Comment: Проблема-то в чём? Ссылка - это и есть адрес, там максимум что может понадобиться, это обрезать параметры запроса, но это простейшая операция со строками... Что именно у вас не получилось?

Comment: Все ссылки хранятся в `document.links` (JS)

Comment: Текст находится  на странице в обычном <p>...</p>
ссылка может находится в разных местах текста 
пример может ссылки может быть так http:ысв//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/
вот так вот, всегда есть возле ссылки http приставка, ссылка может вести на разные сайты 
ссылок может быть несколько но на один и тот же сайт. в тексте

Comment: покажи наглядно, что ты хочешь сделать? приведи пример своего кода

Comment: кода еще нет просто нужны были советы алгоритмы и конструкции которое могут помочь в данном вопросе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно подойдет такой пример:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>

  <body>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>

    <div id='q'></div>

    <script>
      $('#q').load('https://crossorigin.me/http://ru.stackoverflow.com #nav-questions');
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Что парсим:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Здесть я с помощью jQuery, загружаю в **div** с **id = q** текст из блока **#nav-questions** на сайте ru.stackoverflow.com. Используя для этого промежуточный прокси сайт https://crossorigin.me

Comment: частично то что нужно, но не совсем...